# Not entering the if block

Tags: javascript, algorithm, maps

```js
const words = [
  "a",
  "alien",
  "born",
  "less",
  "lien",
  "never",
  "nevertheless",
  "new",
  "newborn",
  "the",
  "zebra",
  "zebra",
];
let compoundArr = [];
let memo = new Map();

setFixes = () => {
  for (let word of words) {
    for (let i = 1; i < word.length; i++) {
      const prefix = word.substring(0, i);
      const suffix = word.substring(i);
      if (memo.get(prefix)) return;
      else {
        if (words.includes(prefix)) memo.set(prefix, true);
      }
      if (memo.get(suffix)) return;
      else {
        if (words.includes(suffix)) memo.set(suffix, true);
      }
    }
  }
};

findCompound = () => {
  setFixes();
  for (let word of words) {
    for (let i = 1; i < word.length; i++) {
      const prefix = word.substring(0, i);
      const suffix = word.substring(i);
      if (memo.get(prefix) === true && memo.get(suffix) === true) {
        compoundArr.push(word);
      }
    }
  }
  return compoundArr;
};

findCompound();
console.log(compoundArr);
```

Hi, I am using a map here to store the prefixes and suffixes to avoid searching for same characters and bigger parts if possible. However I noticed that it never reads from the stored values, it skips this '`if (memo.get(prefix)) return`' and '`if (memo.get(suffix)) return`' part and moves to searching in the words array again. How can we solve this issue?

Comment: If you're always setting the value to `true`, you should use a `Set` rather than `Map`.

Comment: `return` exits the entire function. Use `continue` to go to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: And if you use `continue` when the prefix is found, you'll never test the suffix. Is that what you want?

Comment: I don't really understand what this is trying to do, so I don't know how to advise yiou to rewrite it. But you need to think carefully about each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some issues and remarks:

- The function ends when a `return` is executed, so as soon as a prefix/suffix is found to already be in the Map, the function stops any further processing. Instead of `return` you'll want to just skip the part that writes to the Map for that particular string only.
- As your code only ever uses and checks for the value `true` in the Map, you can do with just a Set.
- Your function variables are implicitly declared as globals. It is better practice to use `const` to define them, or use the `function` statement.
- Use function parameters so that it is clear which variables might get used by them. And if the function *creates* a data structure, then have it *return* it (instead of mutating a global variable). Leave it to the caller to assign the function result to its own variables (which might then be global).
- To avoid scanning the `words` array repeatedly, it would be better to turn that array into a Set once, and then use `has` instead of `includes`.
- As a compound word might consist of words that occur multiple times as prefixes and suffixes, you'll want the list of compound words to also be collected as a Set -- to avoid duplicates. You can turn it into an array as a final step.

```js
const setFixes = (words) => {
  const wordSet = new Set(words); // To speed up look-up
  const fixes = new Set(); // Instead of Map
  for (const word of words) {
    for (let i = 1; i < word.length; i++) {
      const prefix = word.substring(0, i);
      const suffix = word.substring(i);
      // Don't exit the function here -- just skip
      if (wordSet.has(prefix)) fixes.add(prefix);
      if (wordSet.has(suffix)) fixes.add(suffix);
    }
  }
  return fixes; // Return it
};

const findCompound = (words) => {
  const fixes = setFixes(words);
  const compounds = new Set; // Local; and avoid duplicates
  for (const word of words) {
    for (let i = 1; i < word.length; i++) {
      const prefix = word.substring(0, i);
      const suffix = word.substring(i);
      if (fixes.has(prefix) && fixes.has(suffix)) {
        compounds.add(word);
      }
    }
  }
  return [...compounds]; // Turn to array
};

const words = ["a","alien","born","less","lien","never","nevertheless","new","newborn","the","zebra","zebra",];
const compoundArr = findCompound(words);
console.log(compoundArr);
```

Comment: Wow, now I got a better understanding about where to use maps/sets and so many others you mention.  Thank you so much I learned a lot from your clear and detailed explanation.